Although the Azure Key Vault Secret has been shared with me as a Reader, I am unable to retrieve the secret inside Power Automate
I do not have a license to create Azure Key vault, where I will get this message when I tried to create a  new key vault:-

So our IT admin, has created a key vault for me and a secret >> and he shared the secret with my username as a Reader. But when I tried to Get the secret inside Power Automate using "Get secret" built-in action, I got this error message:-

Operation failed because client does not have permission to perform
the operation on the key vault. Please check your permissions in the
key vault access policies
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal.
clientRequestId: 7eb6f1c3-8b2b-44f2-9111-d57f2cb0cf9a

Here are the connection details inside Power Platform:-


any advice?

Is the permission assigned to you Reader or Key Vault Reader? Please see the permissions here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli#azure-built-in-roles-for-key-vault-data-plane-operations

@GauravMantri Key Vault Reader

I read the documentation again and realized that Key Vault Reader role cannot read secret value. Please ask your IT admin to assign you Key Vault Secrets User permission as well so that you can read secret value.

As per the documentation here, a user with Key Vault Reader role cannot read the secret values. In order to read value of a secret, the user must be assigned Key Vault Secrets User role.

ok will ask >> test and let you know thanks a lot for your help

working now..thanksa lot
